# How can we get the second id for sqlmap

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection

I'm trying to find some vulnerable points in my website. My website like, `www.example.com/index.php?menu_id=1002&news_id=5`. When i trying to find these points with sql map, it tries for menu id. But i want to check the news id. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, sqlmap tries all possible parameters, hence it should include both menu_id and news_id in its execution sequentially.

If, on the other hand, you'd like to skip menu_id and go straight for the second parameter, you could run it as follows:

```
./sqlmap.py -u "http://www.example.com/index.php?menu_id=1002&news_id=5" -p news_id
```

Comment: it worked. And we can change the parameters like "index.php?news_id=5&menu_id=1002". It works too :)